# How to make explicit instantiation of template constexpr variable in C++?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, constexpr, explicit-instantiation

If one has a template constexpr variable (e.g. for computing Fibonacci sequence) and would like to instantiate it for some template argument, must `constexpr` keyword be repeated during instantiation?

```
template<int N> constexpr size_t fib = fib<N-1> + fib<N-2>;
template<> constexpr size_t fib<1> = 1;
template<> constexpr size_t fib<2> = 1;

//template constexpr size_t fib<70>; // GCC error
template size_t fib<70>; // Clang error
```

The problem here is that GCC insists on removing the keyword:

```
error: explicit instantiation shall not use 'constexpr' specifier
```

while Clang insists on keeping it:

```
error: type 'size_t' (aka 'unsigned long') of explicit instantiation of 'fib' does not match expected type 'const size_t' (aka 'const unsigned long')
```

Demo: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/f6rMjz95E

Which compiler is correct here according to the standard?

Comment: why do you need this extra line? https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/8TbjW15Tf

Comment: And visual agree with clang [Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/KrM3azx55).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is probably a Clang bug. From [temp.explicit#3](http://eel.is/c++draft/temp.explicit#3)

> ... An explicit instantiation of a function template, member function of a class template, or **variable template** shall not use the `inline`, **`constexpr`**, or `consteval` specifiers.

(emphasis mine)

Which is exactly what the GCC error message says.

Clang's error message says that `const` is missing from the explicit instantiation, and adding that

```
template size_t const fib<70>;  // ok everywhere
```

does allow Clang to [compile](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/3oqdPfa6P) the code as well.